# Displaying raw JSON in a user friendly way

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-library

I am trying to create a raw JSON viewer for JSON strings. I understand there are apps that already do this but I am looking to load JSON from my server and display it for an internal tool for my company.

I am able to pretty print the JSON values, but this can still be difficult to read. Are there any Android libraries available for displaying color-coded JSON or JSON that can have its items expanded? If not can anyone suggest a way to do so? I've looked into ExpandableListView but this only goes up to two levels deep

Comment: @daarun did find any library?

Comment: @Ajay_Reddy Unfortunately I did not

Answer (score -2):

Recommend you to see [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), it simplify JSON.

Comment: How does this solve my issue of displaying the JSON in app?

Comment: There are no views associated with the GSON library. You are incorrect